# Unable to open visual basic 6 project on visual basic 8

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I've created a project on VB6 at but when I am opening it on VB8, it shows the following error:
[image: error]

How to fix it?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896292/you-receive-a-the-remote-procedure-call-failed-error-message-when-you-upgrade-a-visual-basic-6-0-project-to-visual-studio-net-2003-or-visual-studio-2005-on-windows-server-2003-sp1-or-on-windows-xp-sp2

Comment: Please give more details: project type (exe, dll / ocx).

Comment: Did you try to do the conversion to .net on Visual Basic 2008 Express, rather than on Visual Basic 2005 ?

Comment: It was a .vbs project and i dont have VB2008 i have VB6 VB8 and VB2013

Answer (score 1):

As listed by GSerg in the comments, this appears to be a known issue documented in Microsoft Knowledge Base article 896292: [You receive a "The remote procedure call failed" error message when you upgrade a Visual Basic 6.0 project to Visual Studio .NET 2003 or Visual Studio 2005 on Windows Server 2003 SP1 or on Windows XP SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896292/you-receive-a-the-remote-procedure-call-failed-error-message-when-you-upgrade-a-visual-basic-6-0-project-to-visual-studio-net-2003-or-visual-studio-2005-on-windows-server-2003-sp1-or-on-windows-xp-sp2)

To reproduce the solution here:

> ### Cause
>
> This behavior occurs because the VBU.exe tool has compatibility issues with the Data Execution Prevention (DEP) option.
>
> Note: The VBU.exe tool starts when you upgrade the Visual Basic 6.0 project by using the Visual Basic Upgrade Wizard in the Microsoft Visual Studio .NET IDE.
>
> ### Workaround
>
> To work around this behavior, add the VBU.exe tool to the DEP exclusion list. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click System. The System Properties dialog box appears.
> 2. Click the Advanced tab, and then click Settingsunder Performance. The Performance Options dialog box appears.
> 3. Click the Data Execution Prevention tab. Verify that the Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select option is selected
>
>    Note By default, the Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select option is selected in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 (SP1).
> 4. Click Add. Locate and then click to select VBU.exe. Click Open.
> 5. In the warning box, click OK. VBU.exe now appears in the DEP program area.
> 6. Click Apply, and then click
>      OK. A dialog box appears that states that you must restart the computer for the setting to take effect. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try do divide your project to small projects(or comment large part of your project) a try again in each small project.
The idea is to find the function that is production the error.

My intuition is telling me that maybe is a DLL or OCX problem. Try to see all the external DLL or OCX calls and remove from the original project and try again the upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Most developers who move their VB6 projects to .Net do not even try to port them over.  Even with third-party "conversion" software, the effort can be incredibly tedious.  So much so, that most developers simply re-write the application completely.  Consider it a move to a different language.  In fact, some developers use that opportunity to port it to C# instead.  I'm a die-hard VB6 user/fan but were I to attempt to port my 200 form accounting application, I'd just re-write it in C#.  I started porting it, tried third-party conversion apps, just wasn't worth it.